# How to set the value of first input type text in document's first form using mshtml in C#?

Tags: c#, html, mshtml

I am trying to set the value of first input type text in document's first form. See the code below.

```
HTMLDocument htmldoc = new HTMLDocumentClass();  
htmldoc = (HTMLDocument)WebBrowser.Document;  
HTMLFormElement fm = (HTMLFormElement)htmldoc.forms.item(0);
```

In the above code I am getting first form as a form object. Now I want to find the first input type text in this form and set the value of that textbox.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

loop in all elements in form

```
   private void button5_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var htmldoc = (HTMLDocument)webBrowser1.Document.DomDocument;
        HTMLFormElement fm = (HTMLFormElement)htmldoc.forms.item(0);
        foreach (IHTMLElement item in (IHTMLElementCollection)fm.all)
        {
            var textbox = item as IHTMLInputElement;
            if (textbox != null)
            {
                textbox.value = "your text";
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: it is giving the error : "foreach statement cannot operate on variables of type 'object' because 'object' does not contain a public definition for 'GetEnumerator'"

Comment: hmm, what's your .net framework version, fm.all should be dynamic, can you try to cast it as collection: `foreach (IHTMLElement item in (IHTMLElementCollection)fm.all)`

Comment: i have updated my code with your answer and it removed the error successfully. But, now it is doing nothing on executing the code. I troubleshooted the code with messagebox. Here loop iterates only once. my .net framework version is 4.0

Comment: I've updated the code to test with google.com page, which it will set all input element value = "your test", and you will see "your test" on search box

Comment: your code worked like a charm. thanks for the solution. one last thing i want to know is in this code if i found `textbox.type = button`. then how to invoke it's click event.

Comment: or you can give me the second solution by providing the code for form submission like fm.submit()

Comment: I think if you know that element is button, you can cast it to some kind of `IHTMLInputButtonElement` , and call click method (I don't have computer here )

Comment: Thanks @nhabuiduc. I have found the solution with your clue. I did not invoke the submit button instead I have submitted the form after head-banging sometime on it. Thank you very much.